# How to select min time and max time of a particular column?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table in my database which look like as mention below:

```
EnNo     DateTime               
-------- -------------------
1        2015-01-22 11:30:51
1        2015-01-22 11:30:51
1        2015-01-22 18:30:42
1        2015-01-22 10:30:00
1        2015-01-22 18:30:00
1        2015-01-22 18:30:00
2        2015-01-22 11:59:31
2        2015-01-30 18:52:30
```

Now I want to get In time and out time from DateTime column and after the actual output which I expected its look like:

```
EnNo     In                   Out
-------- -------------------  -------------------
1        11:30:51             18:30:42   
1        10:30:00             18:30:00
2        11:59:31             18:52:30
```

I have using the following query to get the expected output but its not working and i.e.

```
select `EnNo`, time(min(`DateTime`)) as `In`, time(max(`DateTime`)) as `out` from attandance group by `EnNo`,time(`DateTime`)
```

Which give the following output

```
EnNo     In                   Out
-------- -------------------  -------------------
1        10:45:21             10:45:21
1        10:45:46             10:45:46
1        10:45:48             10:45:48
1        10:47:03             10:47:03
```

So, How can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: How do you detect a particular time entry as in or out ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid look at my query

Comment: You are grouping with DateTime thats why you get same min and max times, try removing that. But you'll still not get the desired output. No way to distinguish which in time is related to the out time with the data you present us

Comment: Does it work when you remove time()?

Answer (score 0):

use simple query :

it will consider lowest time is in time and highest time out time for particular date

```
 select EnNo,min(DateTime) as in_time, max(DateTime) as out_time
from attandance
group by EnNo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
select `EnNo`, DATE_FORMAT(min(`DateTime`),'%H:%i:%s') as `In`, DATE_FORMAT(max(`DateTime`),'%H:%i:%s') as `out` 
from attandance group by `EnNo`
```

Comment: it throw error i.e. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group by `EnNo` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2

Comment: unexpected output just look my second table as I mention above the question that is my expected output :(

Comment: What's the output you're currently seeing in my query? I'm not on my working PC currently

Comment: You can't get your expected output from your data with a simple sql query because there is not enough data to assosiate an in time with an out time.

Comment: as per the query when I use group by EnNo it combine all result which I don't want group by EnNo

Comment: Upon checking the question again, I will agree to @Dimitris Filippou's comment